# In Mongoose if my child objects have references to the parents how would I populate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

My relationship example:

```
classroom:{
    id: 0,
    name: "123"
}

children : {
    name: "teddy"
    id: 0,
    classroom_id: 0;
}

//goal
clasroom: {
    id: 0,
    name: "123",
    children: [{
        name: "teddy"
        id: 0,
    }]
}
```

What sort of mongoose query would I spin up to return the goal object. I'm worried I'm using mongoDB to much like SQL

Comment: Are classroom and children 2 different schemas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have different collections for classroom and children, then that can't be done. Also since a classroom -> children is a one to many relationship, it's not advisable to embed the children object into classroom document in arrays.

The only thing you can do here is to query the children collection for all the documents that has the specified classroom_id.

```
db.children.find({classroom_id: 0}).toArray(function(err, children){
if(err) console.log(err);
   var classroom = {};
   classroom.id = 0;
   classroom.name = "123";
   classroom.children = [];
   classroom.children.push(children);
});
```

This would find all the documents from the children collection that has a classroom_id of 0, and then will add the resulting documents to the classroom object. This is how it can be done in Node.js

Answer (score 0):

Using mongodb 3.2 aggregation [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operator (left outer join in mongodb)

```
db.classroom.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup : {
        'from' : 'children',
        'localField': '_id',
        'foreignField': 'classroom_id',
        'as': 'children'
      }
    }
]);
```

Getting result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c33ed80a3fba192138e2ac"), 
    "name" : "History", 
    "children" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56c33e6b0a3fba192138e2a8"), 
            "name" : "John", 
            "classroom_id" : ObjectId("56c33ed80a3fba192138e2ac")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56c33e820a3fba192138e2aa"), 
            "name" : "Bob", 
            "classroom_id" : ObjectId("56c33ed80a3fba192138e2ac")
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c33eef0a3fba192138e2ae"), 
    "name" : "English", 
    "children" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56c33f350a3fba192138e2b0"), 
            "name" : "Tom", 
            "classroom_id" : ObjectId("56c33eef0a3fba192138e2ae")
        }
    ]
}
```

Also you can format result using [$project](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operator

My collections are:

classroom

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c33ed80a3fba192138e2ac"), 
    "name" : "History"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c33eef0a3fba192138e2ae"), 
    "name" : "English"
}
```

children

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c33e6b0a3fba192138e2a8"), 
    "name" : "John", 
    "classroom_id" : ObjectId("56c33ed80a3fba192138e2ac")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c33e820a3fba192138e2aa"), 
    "name" : "Bob", 
    "classroom_id" : ObjectId("56c33ed80a3fba192138e2ac")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c33f350a3fba192138e2b0"), 
    "name" : "Tom", 
    "classroom_id" : ObjectId("56c33eef0a3fba192138e2ae")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do this to get an array containing list of all classrooms and children in those classrooms

```
result = [], i=0;
db.classroom.find().exec(function(err, rooms) {
    rooms.forEach(function(room){
        var classroom = {id:room.id, name:room.name};
        db.children.find({classroom_id:room.id}).exec(function(err, res){
            classroom["children"] = res;
            result.push(classroom);
            i++;
            if(i == rooms.length) {
                console.log(result);   // prints an array of objects listing all classrooms and students in them in format you wanted.
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Rather than using a forEach loop, you can simply map the classroom ids to a string array and query the children using $in. That's the solution I have right now, I came here looking for a better way to to it